# Where is the error in this parameterization?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The problem is thus: find $$\int_c (x+2y)\mathrm{d}x+x^2\mathrm{d}y \space \mathrm{where \space C \space consists \space of \space \space line \space segments \space} (0,0)\space \mathrm{to} \space (2,1)\space \mathrm{and} \space(2,1) \space \mathrm{to} \space (3,0)$$

The first line is described by $y=\frac{1}{2}x$ and the second line is described by $y=-x$.  In both cases I let $x=t$, for $y=\frac{1}{2}t$ and $y=-t$ respectively.

This leads to:
$$\int_0^2(t+t)(1)\mathrm{d}t+\int_2^3t^2(\frac{1}{2})\mathrm{d}t=\frac{16}{3}$$ which is correct according to the student solutions manual.

For the second Line, I get:
$$\int_2^3(2-2t)(1)\mathrm{d}t+\int_2^3t^2(-1)\mathrm{d}t=-\frac{53}{6}$$
which is wrong, according to the SSM.

I did this all by hand twice.  Could someone please be so kind as to tell me what I'm snagged on?

Comment: Why is the second line defined by $y=-x$? The endpoints sum to 3, not to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line is not $y=-x$.  What is it?
 Hint: you have the right slope, but it needs to go through (3,0).